# Cheap solid equipment wire for breadboard from online shop?

Tags: prototyping, wire, breadboard

I need breadboard wire for fast prototyping. It can apparently be 22AWG or 24AWG, acccording to [this reply about stranded VS solid wire.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/621/stranded-vs-solid-wire/624#624) Because it is for prototyping, I am not looking for expensive wires with excellent electrical shielding and such things -- just simple wires to plug into breadboard and reuse it fast: connect, reconnect, etc without getting them broken. Where do you get your solid experimenting wires?

**Example**

> Huge price differences: [Farnell Finland 66.7EUR](http://fi.farnell.com/tyco-electronics-raychem/fldwc0311-0-25-0/wire-0-25mm-black-100m/dp/797972?Ntt=TYCO+ELECTRONICS+/+RAYCHEM+-+FLDWC0311-0.25-0+-+FLEXLITE+WIRE+0.25MM+BLACK+100M), [Farnell UK CPC 23Pounds](http://cpc.farnell.com/tyco-electronics-raychem/fldwc0311-0-25-2/flexlite-wire-0-25mm-red-100m/dp/CB04715?Ntt=WIRE+0.25MM+RED+100M), cannot find in eBay or Dealextreme, nearly out of stock in CPC Farnell.

Comment: I see several options for 22 and 24 AWG insulated wire in 1 meter and 4 meter lengths for under $2 w/free-ship, on eBay.com.

Comment: A good cheap source that's available all over the place is the solid conductors in CAT5 cable.

Comment: @ScottSeidman that is true -- that is what I have mentioned in my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fast**

- *"Male to Male Solderless Flexible Breadboard Jumper Cables"* that you connect to your breadboard and let say female sockets in your Arduino/Lauchpad/etc.
- Also try *"Female to Female Jumper Cables"*. They are pretty useful in fast prototyping.

**Cheap**

- Buy network cable such as Cat 5/6 and take out the wires, more [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/621/stranded-vs-solid-wire/623#62). It is a reusable and cheap solution. Yet there are different types of RJ45-headed cables: one of mine is stranded copper (cannot cut it with my tools) and one is solid wire (soft). The last fits to breadboard but try to see the cables first, large differences in quality.

Answer (score 2):

[Bitsbox](http://www.bitsbox.co.uk/cable/cable.html) sell *Single Core 1/06mm* at 12p/metre for up to 100m (Non UK buyers limited to 10m per order)

[Rapid Electronics](http://www.rapidonline.com/productinfo.aspx?tier1URL=Cables-Connectors&tier2URL=Equipment-Wire&tier3URL=Equipment-Wire&tier4URL=1-0.6mm-Single-core-equipment-wire-on-100m-reels&moduleno=62317) have *Single Core 1/06mm* for £4.05 per 100m roll 
or 11 100m rolls (one of each colour) for £44.59